# Python Menu not looping?

Tags: python, loops, menu

Alright, forgive me, this is my first question here. Also, still new to programming.

Anyways, I've been writing a program that would maintain a grocery list. The main idea is that you can add groceries, remove them, change them, check the lists, and exit the program.

I have pretty much everything working, however, my problem is that if the user selects, for example, option 1, they can do so indefinitely (as designed), but when they go to option 2, the program will stop when they try and go back to option one (also similar for 3 back to 2 or 1 and 4 to a lower number).

The principle program is:

```
import moduloListas as mod
abarrotes=[]
frutas=[]
limpieza=[]
listaTotal=[abarrotes,frutas,limpieza]



opcion=mod.menu()

while opcion=='1':
    listaTotal=mod.ingresar(listaTotal)
    opcion=mod.menu()


while opcion=='2':
    listaTotal=mod.eliminar(listaTotal)
    opcion=mod.menu()



while opcion=='3':
    listaTotal=mod.cambiar(listaTotal)
    opcion=mod.menu()


while opcion=='4':
    print "\nAbarrotes: ",listaTotal[0]
    print "\nFrutas:    ",listaTotal[1]
    print "\nLimpieza:  ",listaTotal[2]
    opcion=mod.menu()
```

and the menu is:

```
def menu():
    print "___....----Menu Principal----....___"
    print "1.    Ingresar un articulo"
    print "2.    Eliminar un articulo"
    print "3.    Cambiar un articulo"
    print "4. Mostrar las listas de articulos"
    print "5.     Salir de Programa"
    print "\n"
    posibles=['1','2','3','4','5']
    opcion=raw_input("Por favor hacer una seleccion: ")
    while opcion not in posibles:
        print "Por favor, solo ingresa 1,2,3,4 o 5"
        opcion=raw_input("Por favor hacer una seleccion: ")
    return opcion
```

Comment: You can't go to a lower number because you've already failed that test and no such test exists in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by changing the `while` loops to.

```
while True:
    opcion=mod.menu()
    if opcion=='1':
        listaTotal=mod.ingresar(listaTotal)
    elif opcion=='2':
        listaTotal=mod.eliminar(listaTotal)
    elif opcion=='3':
        listaTotal=mod.cambiar(listaTotal)
    elif opcion=='4':
        print "\nAbarrotes: ",listaTotal[0]
        print "\nFrutas:    ",listaTotal[1]
        print "\nLimpieza:  ",listaTotal[2]
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the first block of code to the following:

```
import moduloListas as mod
abarrotes = []
frutas = []
limpieza = []
listaTotal = [abarrotes, frutas, limpieza]

opcion = mod.menu()
while opcion != '5':
    if opcion == '1':
        listaTotal = mod.ingresar(listaTotal)
    elif opcion == '2':
        listaTotal = mod.eliminar(listaTotal)
    elif opcion == '3':
        listaTotal = mod.cambiar(listaTotal)
    elif opcion == '4':
        print "\nAbarrotes: ", listaTotal[0]
        print "\nFrutas:    ", listaTotal[1]
        print "\nLimpieza:  ", listaTotal[2]
    opcion = mod.menu()
```

Comment: Ah.....excellent. Seems so obvious....not sure how I missed something like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

do

```
while True:
    if opcion == '1':
        ...
    if opcion=='4':
       ....
    opcion = input()
```

And then of course, there's got to be some exit option... '5' or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

The way your code flows means that once you have moved to a number lower than one, you cannot move back "up" the program flow. Trying to change your variable `opcion` again means that the truth statement is evaluated as false, breaking the while loop.

Your code:

```
while opcion=='2':
listaTotal=mod.eliminar(listaTotal)
opcion=mod.menu()
```

So changing `opcion` breaks that loop and moves to the next section of your code (downwards), meaning it seems to work when moving down numbers but not up.

Instead you should use a single while loop with `if` and `elif` statements.

```
while True:
    opcion = mod.menu()
    if "1" in opcion:
        listaTotal=mod.ingresar(listaTotal)
    ...
```

And so on, as in Sukrit Kalra's answer (I was just hoping to clarify why this happens).